# Why doesn't my canvas animation show?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have been working on a canvas animation of a circle that moves in a random direction, and every second the direction changes. I do that by changing a velocity vector every second by repeatedly calling a function using `setInterval`, while changing the position of the circle's center and drawing it in another function using `requestAnimationFrame`. The result is an empty canvas, and I'm not sure why. The code is split into the following three files:

**random_ball.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Random Ball</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="random_ball.css">
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="random_ball.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**random_ball.css**

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas{
  position: absolute;
  width:  50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  top: 25vh;
  left: 25vw;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**random_ball.js**

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
const TWO_PI = 2*Math.Pi
const R = 25
const MAX_Y = bounds.height - R
const MAX_X = bounds.width - R
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

function randomInterval(min, max){
  return Math.random()*(max - min) + min
}

function randomVelocity(){ // velocity is pixels/sec
  VEL.X = randomInterval(-POS.X + R, MAX_X - POS.X)
  VEL.Y = randomInterval(-POS.Y + R, MAX_Y - POS.Y)
  console.log('VEL: ' + JSON.stringify(VEL))
}

var POS = {X: bounds.height/2, Y: bounds.width/2}
var VEL = {X: 0, Y: 0}
var LAST_TIME = window.performance.now()

function drawCircle(color){
  ctx.strokeStyle = color
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(POS.X, POS.Y)
  ctx.arc(POS.X, POS.Y, R, 0, TWO_PI, true)
  ctx.stroke()
}

function draw(timestamp){
  var dt = (timestamp - LAST_TIME)/1000
  var dx = VEL.X*dt
  var dy = VEL.Y*dt

  drawCircle('#FFFFFF') // erase the old drawing by making it white
  POS.X += dx
  POS.Y += dy
  //console.log('POS: ' + JSON.stringify(POS))
  drawCircle('#000000')
  LAST_TIME = timestamp
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

randomVelocity()
drawCircle('#000000')
setInterval(randomVelocity, 1000) //change velocity every second
requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

I suspect that drawing white over the old circle means the picture is changing too fast for me to see it.

Comment: Is there anything of use in your console that you can share with us?

Comment: Nope, just that the velocity and position seem to update sanely. There are no error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to familiarize yourself with JavaScript syntax rules, and possibly a code checker like JSHint.

The main problem with your code is that you're referencing a nonexistent property of the `Math` object. `Math` has no `Pi` property. It's spelled `PI` (all caps). JavaScript *is* case sensitive about these things.

Next: a more common practice for clearing the canvas is to use `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)`. Here's a JSFiddle to help you see the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/dy2dognp/

Comment: Oh, I knew that it was case sensitive. I just saw code that used has Math.Pi and assumed it was correct. I changed that and I can see drawings now, even though it is a little buggy. I will accept your answer and figure out the rest of my bugs on my own. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Broseph Glad to be of assistance; happy coding!